# CSS/jQuery nth-child for heavily nested div structure

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a pretty heavily nested div structure which I'm trying to sort in 3 columns.

```
<div class="view-content">

<div class="view-grouping">
    <h1>Group 1</h1>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">  
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 1</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 2</div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of Subgroup 1 -->
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 2</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 3</div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of Subgroup 2 -->
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 3</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- end of Subgroup 3 -->
    </div> <!-- end of inner Group 1 wrapper -->
</div> <!-- end of Group 1 -->

<div class="view-grouping">
    <h1>Group 2</h1>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">  
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 4</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 7</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 8</div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of Subgroup 4 -->
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 5</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 9</div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of Subgroup 5 -->
        <div class="views-limit-grouping-group">
            <h2>Subgroup 6</h2>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 11</div>
            </div>
            <div class="views-limit-grouping">
                <div class="custom-widget">Item 12</div>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- end of Subgroup 6 -->
    </div> <!-- end of inner Group 2 wrapper -->
</div> <!-- end of Group 2 -->
```

Every third (3n+3) `.custom-widget` should have a `margin-right: 0;`

If I use:

```
.view-grouping .view-grouping-content .views-limit-grouping-group:nth-child(3n+3) .custom-widget{   
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

it won't work due to the nested div structure.

This is a dynamic layout (using it in a Drupal build) so there can be any number of Groups, Subgroups. Also, there can be any no. if items in any of the previously mentioned grouping DIVs.

For the sake of a simple example I've put the main wrapper at 320px which should wrap 3 elements including the 10px spacing for the first 2 items.

I'm totally fine to use both CSS and jQuery to solve this problem. Do you have any ideas how should I approach this?

Thanks!

P.S. jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6m2bqaa1/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
Use nth-of-type, hopefully it will help you:

.views-limit-grouping-group > div:nth-of-type(3) .custom-widget{margin-right:0}


or you can add whole css as under:

h1, h2 {
    display: none;
}

.views-limit-grouping-group{clear:both; overflow:hidden}

.views-limit-grouping{float:left}

.view-content{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}

.custom-widget{
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.views-limit-grouping-group > div:nth-of-type(3) .custom-widget{
    margin-right: 0;
    background: red;
}

your problem will be solve.
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been fiddling with `nth-of-type` for the past hour but still no luck. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/6m2bqaa1/5/ The selection is weird as you can see. The problem is that the number of divs is not equal in each group. I've also tried to work around `nth-last-of-type` but due to the number of divs this won't work either.

Comment: user this css:h1, h2 {
    display: none;
}

.views-limit-grouping-group{clear:both; overflow:hidden}

.views-limit-grouping{float:left}

.view-content{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}

.custom-widget{
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.views-limit-grouping-group > div:nth-of-type(3) .custom-widget{
    margin-right: 0;
    background: red;
}